# JavaFX Unable To Set Custom Properties

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to implement custom properties into a custom component for my JavaFX application. I've read some tutorials and all have pointed me in the direction of below.

For some reason, it's not working. IntelliJ isn't liking when I try and set the property values inside of the FXML file and the scene builder doesn't show the property either.

**Label Controller:**

```java
public class LabelController {

    @FXML
    public Label label;

    // Define a variable to store the property
    private DoubleProperty amountDue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    // Define a getter for the property's value
    public final double getAmountDue(){return amountDue.get();}

    // Define a setter for the property's value
    public final void setAmountDue(double value){amountDue.set(value);}

    // Define a getter for the property itself
    public DoubleProperty amountDueProperty() {return amountDue;}

    public void onMouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        FadeToHoverColour();
    }

    public void onMouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        FadeToDefaultColour();
    }

    public void FadeToHoverColour() {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), Paint.valueOf("E63700"))));
        timeline.play();
    }

    public void FadeToDefaultColour() {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), Paint.valueOf("FF774D"))));
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

**Label.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="madoc.controllers.components.LabelController">
    <Label fx:id="label"
           text="TEXT"
           onMouseEntered="#onMouseEntered"
           onMouseExited="#onMouseExited">
    </Label>
</VBox>
```

**WelcomeSceneBuilder.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="madoc.controllers.scenes.WelcomeSceneController">
    <fx:include source="./Label.fxml" [NOT WORKING WHEN I TRY TO SET AMOUNT DUE HERE]/>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes/children added to the `<fx:include>` element apply to the result of loading the other fxml, i.e. in this case the type of object created is `VBox`, not `LabelController`. `VBox` does not contain the properties you're trying to assign.

You cannot do this using fxml only. You'd need to use the `initialize` method of the controller to set the property values:

**WelcomeSceneController**

```
@FXML
private LabelController labelController;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    labelController.setAmountDue(...);
}
```

**WelcomeSceneBuilder.fxml**

```xml
...
<fx:include source="./Label.fxml" fx:id="label"/>
...
```

---

You could use [*the Custom Component approach*](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) though which would make the controller and node the same object allowing you to make assignments like these. Lacking inso about the responsibility of the node, I'm keeping `LabelController`, but of course you should choose a better name.

```
package madoc.controllers.components;

...

public class LabelController extends VBox {

    public LabelController() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/madoc/controllers/components/Label.fxml")); // TODO: replace with correct resoure path?
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load fxml file", ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public Label label;

    // Define a variable to store the property
    private final DoubleProperty amountDue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    // Define a getter for the property's value
    public final double getAmountDue(){return amountDue.get();}

    // Define a setter for the property's value
    public final void setAmountDue(double value){amountDue.set(value);}

    // Define a getter for the property itself
    public DoubleProperty amountDueProperty() {return amountDue;}

    ...
}
```

**Label.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox">
    <Label fx:id="label"
           text="TEXT"
           onMouseEntered="#onMouseEntered"
           onMouseExited="#onMouseExited">
    </Label>
</fx:root>
```

**WelcomeSceneBuilder.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import madoc.controllers.components.LabelController?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="madoc.controllers.scenes.WelcomeSceneController">
    <LabelController amountDue="30.05"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I went with the custom component approach you mentioned. Has everything I wanted. Thank you for the help!